# Why does water present in aqueous solution of CuSO4 ionize into H+ and OH- during its electrolysis?

Tags: electrolysis

It’s written in books that during electrolysis of aqueous solutions of $\ce{CuSO4}$ or $\ce{NiSO4}$, the water particles ionize into $\ce{H^+}$ and $\ce{OH^-}$ ions along with dissociation of the ionic salt. Now my question is , why does water ionize along with the dissociation of salt?

I do know that water helps in dissociating the salt by reducing the electrostatic force of attraction between the ions. But why does water break into ions? Is it due to the electricity or the ions of the ionic salt or partial charges on oxygen and hydrogen of a water molecule?

Answer (score 1):

In a solution of $\ce{CuSO4}$ or $\ce{NiSO4}$, water does not dissociate more into $\ce{H+}$ and $\ce{OH-}$ than it does usually. But at the anode, the ion $\ce{SO4^{2-}}$ is not discharged as it may have done when an anion is discharged. Water takes its role and produce electrons instead. The anodic equation is : $$\ce{2H2O -> 4 H+ + O2 + 4 e-}$$ So the cation $\ce{Cu^{2+}}$ or $\ce{Ni^{2+}}$ is discharged at the cathode, and the solution becomes acidic at the anode because of the creation of ions $\ce{H+}$ in solution. The main result is that the ions $\ce{Cu^{2+}}$ or $\ce{Ni^{2+}}$ are progressively replaced by ions $\ce{H+}$ in solution.

It may look as if water has been more "dissociated" into $\ce{H+}$ and $\ce{OH-}$ producing more $\ce{H+}$ and more $\ce{OH-}$, if it is still believed that $\ce{OH-}$ had been discharged at the anode (instead of water) according to $$\ce{? ... 2 OH- -> O2 + H2O + 2 e- ... ?}$$